# Unity adds vertices to the original mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple teapot mesh and a point cache animation that matches that mesh.

Everything is exported from 3DS Max.

When I try to load it into unity, and load the point cache into the mesh, there is a **vertices mismatch**.

Upon further debugging I saw that indeed unity adds more vertices than there is in the original mesh, **which means** I cannot match the point cache animation to the mesh now.

I saw on the [RecalculateNormals](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateNormals.html) page and it say's:

> Imported Meshes sometimes don't share all vertices. For example, a
>   vertex at a UV seam is split into two vertices, so the
>   RecalculateNormals function creates normals that are not smooth at the
>   UV seam.

So, unity adds more vertices to the original mesh.

What can I do to fix that so my point cache match the mesh? there is no documentation how unity does that, nor is there a way to turn it off.

**Note**: I tried changing the import setting (and export setting on max) like:

- Mesh compression -> Nothing
- Optimize mesh -> Nothing
- Keep Quads -> ON
- Weld Vertices -> OFF
- Smoothness Source -> None
- And more...

Everything is set and tested separately & together. Nothing seem to *lower* the vertex count.

Comment: It's not a solution but perhaps help to understand the problem: https://forum.unity.com/threads/vertex-count-increase-unexpectedly-on-import.8479/

Comment: Not sure but you can try import as other formats, maybe `.obj` or try to export your object to `.fbx` then try to import it to blender.

Comment: @Raguel I tried importing both `.obj` and `.fbx` with different export & import settings, both came with the same results

Comment: @DomCR Thanks, I know why they do it, I just try to know HOW they did it, so I can do it with my point cache animation, or how can I turn it off (if possible). Or if anyone have any other solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Vertex duplication is generally unavoidable.

Turning off split per-vertex normals in the fbx exporter settings in max is supposed to solve this problem, but it will remove all seams from your model.

Personally, I would work around this in maxscript by exporting the entire mesh as fbx at each $t instead of writing out the point cache.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using maxscript to do that but I was hoping there is another solution for this problem. There isn't a way to mimic the way Unity does the duplication? so I can duplicate the point cache the same way.

Comment: I've never tried this, but its possible that the triangles are in the same order. If so, you could match up the imported vertex index from unity mesh.indices[triangle * 3 + i] with the Faces[triangle].v[i] array in max.  That way you would know what 3dsmax vertex maps to what unity mesh vertex.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool, the Oasis Mesh Editor, that can Split Vertices and Merge Vertices back together, https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/166155

The Merge Verts tool also has a Max Tolerance setting so that only verts that are closer than this distance will be merged.

Hope this helps anyone looking  =)